# When is (this != this) in C++?

Tags: c++, this, multiple-inheritance

I have a very strange question.

I have a class/function :

```
class MCBSystem {

    [...]

    template <class Receiver>
    void setCallBack(int i, Receiver* receiver, void(Receiver::*function)(void*)) {
        iCallBacks.at(i) = new CallBack<Receiver>(receiver, function, this);
    };
};
```

And I inherit it (multiply) in another class :

```
class MenuBox : public OverlayBox, public HIDListener, public FANLib::MCBSystem {
[...]
};
```

Now, if I call the "setCallBack" function :

```
        menuBox->setCallBack(MenuBox::CLICKED, this, &SubMain::widgetClicked);
```

then "menuBox" has a value say 0x06cf22b8 but inside "setCallBack", "this" is 0x06cf2370.

Can someone explain what on earth is going on?

[EDIT:] The true question is : if I need to store 'this' inside 'setCallBack', how can I check later that 'menuBox == this'?

Many thanks in advace!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, the `this` pointer has to be patched to allow for multiple inheritance polymorphism. As a zeroth-order approximation, an instance of a class `C` that inherits from `A` and `B` can be thought to include an instance of `A` followed by an instance of `B`. Now if you have a pointer to a `C` instance and convert that to an instance of `B`, the `this` pointer must be different because the `B` instance is located after the `C` instance in memory. See [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.23.4735&rep=rep1&type=pdf) for an in-depth discussion.

Little test program:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A { int i; };
struct B { int j; };
struct C: A, B { };

#define PRINT(expr) std::cout << #expr " = " << expr << std::endl

int main() {
  C* c = new C;
  B* b = c;
  PRINT(b);
  PRINT(c);
  PRINT(static_cast<B*>(c));
}
```

Comment: Then, how can I check later that menuBox == this (the one stored inside 'setCallBack'..?

Comment: I think it should work if you cast them to a common base class.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. I solved it by doing :
((FANLib::MCBSystem*)menuBox) == this, and yes, it worked!

Comment: Use a C++ cast, e.g. `static_cast` instead.

Comment: @FredOverflow: This won't help.

Comment: In general, don't cast. Either the conversion is implicit and the comparison OK, or ambiguous and not OK.

Answer (score 1):

Given any pointer to an object, it's value will be different based on whatever it is cast to.

Within a member function of `MenuBox`, `this` points to the `MenuBox` part of the object in question.

However, in `setCallBack`, it is being cast to a pointer to the `Receiver` part of the object.

To put it another way, `this` will always equal `this`, but for any pointer `p` `static_cast<MenuBox>(p)` will never equal `static_cast<Receiver>(p)`.